# Synching iphone with banshee/rhythmbox ubuntu 14.04

Tags: rhythmbox, banshee, iphone

I think I have this bug.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/1132215?comments=all

Any app crashes as soon as it tries to interact with it (ex: drag and dropping a file to it's representation in the app's iphone icon)

I need a workaround allowing me to get my music onto my phone and be able to browse them with the iPod app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifuse` to mount your iphone in ubuntu.

Install it by typing following command in terminal :

`sudo apt-get install ifuse`

It is a FUSE filesystem driver which uses libiphone to connect to iPhone
and iPod Touch devices without needing to "jailbreak" them.